# Web Scraping with BeautifulSoup: Fetching fundsupermart data

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using beautifulsoup to fetch the recommended funds daily from fundsupermart https://www.fundsupermart.co.in/main/research/recommendedFundsNew.svdo? but I am unable to get the class and other attributes of a fund.

When I am using the select statement 
soup.select('.table_bdrow1_style')

I am not getting the class and other attributes of the fund. I am just getting the name of funds. Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: show your code. `select()` can't do everything - you need more code to get data.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.fundsupermart.co.in/main/research/recommendedFundsNew.svdo')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
trs = soup.find_all(class_="table_bdrow1_style")

for tr in trs:
    row = list(tr.stripped_strings)
    print(row)
```

out:

```
['BSL FRONTLINE EQUITY FUND- GROWTH', 'Large Cap', '9.69', '3.87', '17.2', '17.01']
['ICICI PRUDENTIAL FOCUSED BLUECHIP EQUITY FUND- GROWTH', 'Large Cap', '9.11', '3.05', '15.34', '14.97']
['SBI BLUE CHIP FUND- GROWTH', 'Large Cap', '7.82', '6.49', '19.69', '18.73']
['AXIS EQUITY FUND- GROWTH', 'Large Cap', '1.08', '-1.44', '11.86', '14.31']
['BNP PARIBAS EQUITY FUND- GROWTH', 'Large Cap', '0.34', '0.89', '14.83', '14.96']
['RELIANCE TOP 200 FUND- GROWTH', 'Large Cap', '5.66', '2.21', '19.39', '17.18']
```

hrml.parse Version:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.fundsupermart.co.in/main/research/recommendedFundsNew.svdo')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
trs = soup.find_all(class_="table_bdrow1_style")

for tr in trs:
    row = list(tr.stripped_strings)
    print(row)
```

out:

```
['BSL FRONTLINE EQUITY FUND- GROWTH']
['ICICI PRUDENTIAL FOCUSED BLUECHIP EQUITY FUND- GROWTH']
['SBI BLUE CHIP FUND- GROWTH']
['AXIS EQUITY FUND- GROWTH']
['BNP PARIBAS EQUITY FUND- GROWTH']
['RELIANCE TOP 200 FUND- GROWTH']
```

if you still get error, please post you code and error message.

Comment: r = requests.get('https://www.fundsupermart.co.in/main/research/recommendedFundsNew.svdo')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
trs = soup.find_all(class_="table_bdrow1_style")
trs

Why doesn't this code works? Why html parser doesn't work ?

Comment: With html parser, you were not able to get the required results which you got only through lxml? Why is it so ?

Comment: i just notice that, i check the source html code from both parser, they are all the same, so i am confused too.